# I need to mute sound vars by their name

Tags: jquery, html, audio, var, mute

I need to be able to mute all sounds that I have. the sounds arn't continuous so .pause() is not a solution. this is what my audio looks like:

```
var soundName = new Audio("sound/soundname.wav","sound/soundname.ogg","sound/soundname.mp3");
    soundName.play();
```

I want to mute it the moment I click on a div called #mute
but this doesn't work:

```
$("#mute").click(function(e) { 
soundName.mute()
});
```

I do not understand a single thing about the HTML 5 player plugins so that's why I need a temporary solution untill I do understand that.
I've tried many things. Including the simple solutions. but my audio needs to be able to overlap. and that is only possible with the :

```
var name = new audio();
```

as far as i know

Answer (score 0):

Try this line. This is the proper mute propery to mute currently playing audio.

```
soundName.muted = true;
```

Comment: My code alos seizes to function if I put this anywhere.
As I was saying before: the sounds arn't continuous. i meant to say that. it's not a track that is playing it's sounds that play when you do stuff. the soundName.muted doesn't seem to work for this